# How to add y-axis label to df.boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I generate a boxplot out of a dataframe with:

```
bplot = df.boxplot(
    column=column_name,
    by=list1,
    fontsize=8,
    layout=(2,1),
    rot=90,
    figsize=(25,20)
)
```

Where `df` is my dataframe, `column_name` is my wanted column and `list1` is the list to use for groupby?

I want to label my y-axis with a string. Tried this:

```
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 3):

DataFrame.boxplot() function returns Axes object. So, instead of using `bplot.ylabel('ylabel')` which is the function for pyplot object, try to use:

```
bplot.set_ylabel('ylabel')
```

If you still got errors, make sure to write the line right after you call the boxplot() function.

As an alternative, you could also create pyplot subplots first which generates the axes object that you need. And then you can specify the axes object on the boxplot function arguments:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplot()
ax = df.boxplot(
    column=column_name,
    by=list1,
    fontsize=8,
    layout=(2,1),
    rot=90,
    figsize=(25,20),
    ax=ax
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need first to define the `pd.DataFrame.boxplot()` `return_type` parameter as `'axes'`. It will return a `pandas.Series` with single value containing the `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object. You can then manipulate this object like any matplotlib axes object:

```
bbplot = df.boxplot(column=column_name,
                    by=list1,
                    fontsize=8,
                    layout=(2,1),
                    rot=90,
                    figsize=(25,20),
                    return_type='axes')

bbplot[0].set_ylabel('yaxis')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`bplot.set_ylabel('ylabel')`

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_ylabel'  ---- is the error I get

Comment: 1. what version of `pandas` do you have?
2. do you assign any results to variable `bplot`?
3. can you show us results of `type(bplot)`?
4. according to documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html should return type `matplotlib.axes` which has method ylabel and which is different than `numpy.ndarray`.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:
e.g.

```
df.boxplot(column = ['Funds']).set_ylabel('million USD')
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

plt.gca().set_ylabel('yLabel')